# Change AlertDialog Cancel Behaviour

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to have my alert dialog not only close itself when cancelled but also go back to the activity before the one it was called in. Is there a cancel function I can override or is it better to `setCancelable(false)` and use a KeyListener on the back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using AlertDialog.Builder to create your AlertDialog you can set a OnCancelListener ([OnCancelListener docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29)).

Then in the listener you can call finish() to destroy the activity.